# Does TeamCity expose the base_ref property of GitHub pull request branches?

Tags: github, teamcity, pull-request

We've got a special TeamCity configuration for building GitHub pull requests, using the standard `+:refs/pull/*/merge` refspec on the GitHub repo.

So while that lets our configuration build the pull request, what I'd like to do is access the pull requests source and target branch names to do some special processing / error handling.

If `ProjectRepo` has pull request `1234` raised to merge `FredsFork/feature/FizzBuzzCalculator` into `ProjectRepo/master`, then TeamCity will attempt to build the `/pull/1234/merge` reference.

I'd like to be able to use the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#get-a-single-pull-request) to query info about PR 1234, and discover that the `base_ref` is `master` and the `head_ref` is `feature/FizzBuzzCalculator`

Specifically, I'd like to use a different checkout directory for different base_refs. We can use incremental builds (under 5 minutes) for all pull requests that target the same branch, but as soon as another PR is raised that targets a different upstream branch, we are forced to do a full rebuild, which adds 40 minutes to our build time.

So if I can keep unrelated PRs separate, our PR builds speed up incredibly.

Right now, TeamCity thinks the name of the branch it is building is `/pull/1234/merge`. I'd like to somehow modify the VCS configuration so that the default agent checkout directory is `head_ref`.

Does TeamCity's GitHub integration have any way of exposing this information for a pull request?

Comment: Here is a feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-43759, Please vote for it.

Comment: See a workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42651854/292613

Comment: you could try using `head` in the branch specification instead (i.e. `+:refs/pull/*/head`). note that you will get a checkout on the PR branch, not the merge result of the PR branch.