# Build pull requests to specific branch using TeamCity and Github

Tags: github, teamcity

I want TeamCity to build all pull requests to specific target branch, e.g. `develop`.
So, I want to build following pull requests:

```
develop...foo_branch
develop...bar_branch
```

and skip this:

```
master...foo_branch
master...bar_branch
```

In TeamCity I can define `branch specification` to build all pull requests:

```
+:refs/pull/*/head
```

or define filter by source branch:

```
-:refs/heads/(spikes-*)
```

But I need filter by **target** branch. Is it possible?

Comment: Would love an answer to this one, bit by it.

Comment: Would like to know the answer, too.

Comment: I have the same question. Would love to get an answer

Answer (score 7):

I've written a script to work around this issue. It can be run as one of the first build steps in TC's build configuration. The script will ask for pull request details from Github, parse the response and inject source and target branch names as TeamCity parameters and environment variables. In the next build steps, you'll be able to abort the build or do whatever else you need based on these variables.

https://gist.github.com/dzzh/a6d8631e9617777fb5237bc9ec7b356b

For the script to work, you'll have to submit PR's id as a command-line argument. We use the recommended refspec (refs/pulls/*/head) to run our builds, I extract the PR id from it and invoke the script with it.

Comment: How do you cancel the builds without failure messages showing up in your GitHub PRs? I've found https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Failure+Conditions which would let me cause the incorrect build(s) to immediately stop, but won't that still report a failed build to GitHub? So if I build a PR against my `release-2.6` branch but I have 3 build configs, I'd see 2 failure status messages "Build `master` failed"; "Build `release-2.5` failed" and just one success status message "Build `release-2.6` succeeded". Do you know how to abort the build without reporting failure to GitHub?

Answer (score 4):

Currently it's not possible to differentiate pull request branches based on their target branch in TeamCity. Please watch/vote for the request https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-43759 which is planned for the upcoming release.

Answer (score 1):

**Build Feature: Pull Request**

> Pull request support is implemented as a build feature in TeamCity. The feature extends the VCS root’s original branch specification to include pull requests that match the specified filtering criteria.
>
> To configure the pull requests support for a build configuration, go to **Build Configuration Settings | Build Features**, click **Add build feature**, and select the **Pull Requests** feature from the dropdown list in the dialog.

Source: https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2019/08/building-github-pull-requests-with-teamcity/

So the filtering is done with the **Build Feature: Pull Request**, where `By target branch:` should be set to the targetet branch for example `refs/head/master` or `refs/head/myspecialbranch`