# TeamCity always merges into master

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have a pull request on GitHub to merge branch `foo` into `develop` (my default branch). I do have a branch `master` but this is not the branch I want to merge into.

In TeamCity, in VCS roots for my project I have the following setup:

- **Default Branch:** `develop`
- **Branch Specification:** `+:refs/pull/*/merge`

I have published a pull request, but when TeamCity builds the PR it merges `foo` with `master` (not `develop`).

Comment: Please check the AutoMerge build feature settings, it specifies the target branch for merge. If you don't use it and merge inside a build script, then check the script logic.

Comment: This looks quite similar to this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46890527/teamcity-always-merges-into-master. The TeamCIty feature request linked in one of the answers there (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-43759) is probably what you need; if that was implemented, you'd be able to access the merge's target branch in the TeamCity VCS roots. If you want that feature, the best thing to do right now is to go to JetBrain's bug tracker and vote for it, so that it moves up on their priority list and they work on it sooner.

Comment: @rmunn I think the question you've linked is this question...

Comment: @JamesMonger - Whoops! Thanks for the catch; I meant to link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483842/build-pull-requests-to-specific-branch-using-teamcity-and-github, which mentions https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-43759 in one of its answers.

Comment: Thanks @rmunn - I've voted to close this as a duplicate